# Can you search an entire visual studio project for strings containing a word?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

I have a large website project that I’m standardizing variables for, is it possible to search for strings containing a certain word in visual studio? For example the first strings I need to locate contain the word template, is it possible to find all strings that contain this word?

I’m currently going page to page and looking for items or tooltips with the words. Any tips are well appreciated <3

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2022

Comment: Ctrl+F is your friend

Answer (score 0):

To search for text inside the whole solution or project use `CTRL+SHIFT+F`